# Dash dcc.Slider mouseup and drag event

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a dcc.Slider object which I would like to have an **@app.callback** for a *drag* event(update the state of the slider in a ) and also an **@app.callback** for an *mouseup* event, which will update a graph that I have. My question, is this doable with dash? The documentation for mouseup in updatemode mentions drag_value, but i cannot see how to use it in **@app.callback**.

Here is my plot:

```
app.title = "Plot Log"
app.layout = html.Div(
[
    dcc.Graph(id="graph"),
    dcc.Slider(0, slider_length, 1,
        id='slider-updatemode',
        value=2,
        updatemode='mouseup'
    ),
    html.Div(id='updatemode-output-container', style={'margin-top': 20})
    ],
    style={"width": "500"},
)
```

Reading documentation, using drag_value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, one can have a callback for handling the *drag* event and another one for the *mouseup* event. Quoting the part of the doc you are referring to for clarity :

> If you want different actions during and after drag, leave `updatemode`
> as `mouseup` and use `drag_value` for the continuously updating value.

Here an example that displays the drag value as it changes, and updates the graph on mouseup :

```py
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id="graph"),
    dcc.Slider(min=-5, max=5, step=0.01, value=1,
               marks={i: str(i) for i in range(-5, 6)},
               id='slider-updatemode',
               updatemode='mouseup',
               ),
    html.Div(id='updatemode-output-container', style={'margin-top': 20})
])


@app.callback(Output('updatemode-output-container', 'children'),
              Input('slider-updatemode', 'drag_value'))
def display_value(drag_value):
    return f'Slider Value: {drag_value}'


@app.callback(Output('graph', 'figure'),
              Input('slider-updatemode', 'value'))
def update_graph(value):
    x = np.linspace(0.1, 10, 1000)
    y = [x**value for x in x]
    return go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(x=x, y=y)])
```